# Use of loss functions in updating weights of neural networks

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, loss-function

I am confused about the use of `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(prediction - output))` line.

While doing back propagation, the output should be a vector as each output neuron's predicted output is subtracted from the actual output and this is repeated for all output neurons, hence we get a vector of size `(n,1)`. If we use `tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(prediction - output))`, the output is a single value. I am unable to understand how this single value will be propagated to update the weights. Shouldn't it be always a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are correct that the loss must be a vector. However, This line

```
tf.reduce_mean
```

is taking the average loss over batches, not over the vector. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201452/is-it-common-practice-to-minimize-the-mean-loss-over-the-batches-instead-of-the